# how to convert from double with decimal point number to binary in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

i'm wrtting a code in visual studio  c# that converts integers from  binary to decimal mode and from decimal mode to binary but i want it to converts numbers with decimal points from decimal mode to binary how can i do this please help me and tell me what modifies i must put in my code 
this is my code for the calculator :

```
                    using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        namespace assignment2
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                const int asciiDiff = 48;
                double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;
                double fact = 1;
                int[] iHexaNumeric = new int[] { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
                char[] cHexa = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
                String a = "";
                char op;
                bool b = false;
                const int base10 = 10;
                public Form1()
                {
                  // 

                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "1";
                }

                private void buttonTow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "2";
                }

                private void buttonThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "3";
                }

                private void buttonFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "4";
                }

                private void buttonFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "5";
                }

                private void buttonSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "6";
                }

                private void buttonSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "7";
                }

                private void buttonEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "8";
                }

                private void buttonNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "9";
                }

                private void buttonZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    a = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();

                    DisplayResult.Text = a + "0";
                }

                private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayResult.Text.ToString());
                    op = '+';
                    DisplayResult.Text = string.Empty;
                }

                private void buttonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayResult.Text.ToString());
                    op = '-';
                    DisplayResult.Text = string.Empty;
                }

                private void buttonMultipler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayResult.Text.ToString());
                    op = '*';
                    DisplayResult.Text = string.Empty;
                }

                private void buttonDivider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayResult.Text.ToString());
                    op = '/';
                    DisplayResult.Text = string.Empty;
                }




                private void buttonEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (DisplayResult.Text == "")
                        return;
                    else
                    {

                        try
                        {

                            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayResult.Text.ToString());
                            switch (op)
                            {
                                case '+': //suma
                                    result = (num1 + num2);
                                    DisplayResult.Text = result.ToString();
                                    break;


                                case '-': //resta
                                    result = (num1 - num2);
                                    DisplayResult.Text = result.ToString();
                                    break;

                                case '*': //multiply
                                    result = (num1 * num2);
                                    DisplayResult.Text = result.ToString();
                                    break;

                                case '/': //division
                                    if (num2 != 0)
                                    {
                                        result = (num1 / num2);
                                        DisplayResult.Text = result.ToString();

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        DisplayResult.Text = "Can't divide by 0";
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error occured. Details: " +
                                ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void buttonBackSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        String Value = DisplayResult.Text.ToString();
                        int temp = Value.Length;
                        if (temp == 1)
                            DisplayResult.Text = String.Empty;
                        else
                        {
                            DisplayResult.Text = DisplayResult.Text.Substring(0, temp - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error in buttonBackSpace occured. Details: " +
                            ex.Message);
                    } 
                }

                private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    DisplayResult.Text = String.Empty;
                }
                private void buttonDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                    if (DisplayResult.Text.Contains("."))
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    DisplayResult.Text += ".";


                }

                private void DecimalRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (DecimalRadioButton.Checked == true)
                    {
                        DisplayResult.Text= BaseToDecimal(DisplayResult.Text.ToString(), 2).ToString();

                    }
                    buttonTow.Enabled = true;
                    buttonThree.Enabled = true;
                    buttonFour.Enabled = true;
                    buttonFive.Enabled = true;
                    buttonSix.Enabled = true;
                    buttonSeven.Enabled = true;
                    buttonEight.Enabled = true;
                    buttonNine.Enabled = true;

                }

                private void BinaryRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (BinaryRadioButton.Checked == true)
                    {

                        DisplayResult.Text = DecimalToBase(Convert.ToInt16(DisplayResult.Text.ToString()), 2);

                        buttonTow.Enabled = false;
                        buttonThree.Enabled = false;
                        buttonFour.Enabled = false;
                        buttonFive.Enabled = false;
                        buttonSix.Enabled = false;
                        buttonSeven.Enabled = false;
                        buttonEight.Enabled = false;
                        buttonNine.Enabled = false;
                    }




                }




                string DecimalToBase(int iDec, int numbase)
                {
                    string strBin = "";
                    int[] result = new int[32];
                    int MaxBit = 32;
                    for (; iDec > 0; iDec /= numbase)
                    {
                        int rem = iDec % numbase;
                        result[--MaxBit] = rem;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                        if ((int)result.GetValue(i) >= base10)
                            strBin += cHexa[(int)result.GetValue(i) % base10];
                        else
                            strBin += result.GetValue(i);
                    strBin = strBin.TrimStart(new char[] { '0' });
                    return strBin;
                }

                int BaseToDecimal(string sBase, int numbase)
                {

                    int dec = 0;
                    int b;
                    int iProduct = 1;
                    string sHexa = "";
                    if (numbase > base10)
                        for (int i = 0; i < cHexa.Length; i++)
                            sHexa += cHexa.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    for (int i = sBase.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--, iProduct *= numbase)
                    {
                        string sValue = sBase[i].ToString();
                        if (sValue.IndexOfAny(cHexa) >= 0)
                            b = iHexaNumeric[sHexa.IndexOf(sBase[i])];
                        else
                            b = (int)sBase[i] - asciiDiff;
                        dec += (b * iProduct);
                    }
                    return dec;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the binary representation of 1.1?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Fractions

Answer (score 1):

When converting a number with a decimal point from decimal to binary, this is what you do: first you take the part before the decimal point and convert it (in the usual way) to binary; and the part after the decimal point you multiply by 2 and see if it is >= 1; if it is not, write 0 and keep multiplying. You are done when it is = 1.00. For example:

2.25 -
You take the 0.25;
0.25 * 2 = 0.50 --> `0`,
0.50 * 2 = 1.00 --> `1`, and you just read the numbers.
So, 0.25 would be 0.01 (2.25 would be 10.01 binary.)

Comment: how can i do that as coding in c#

Comment: Well it's simple: take the (for example) 0.25 (x), and do x*=2 while x!=1.00. At each step check: if x>1 write 1 to an array or something, else write 0. At the end just read the numbers from the array.